# How to finish an active debounceTime in OnDestroy

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am currently saving values when a user changes an input field. I don't want to save the value each time a new character is entered so I'm using the rxjs debounceTime to save after 3000ms (just an example) of no changes.

```
this.subscription.add(this.form.controls.inputControl.valueChanges
        .pipe(debounceTime(3000))
        .subscribe(value => {
            // execute HTTP call with value
        }));

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

If the user changes the value and OnDestroy gets called before the 3000ms timer is reached, the call won't get executed no more. I was wondering if there was a way to cancel the active timer and execute all remaining observables before destroying the component.

EDIT: Another option could be that the user gets a warning when there are unsaved changes. Like the way google calendar does when adding a new task and leaving the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const destroyed = new Subject();
const isTimerActive = new BehaviorSubject(false);

const stop$ = combineLatest(destroyed, isTimerActive)
  .pipe(
    filter(([isDestroyed, isTimerActive]) => isDestroyed && !isTimerActive)
  );

src$.pipe(
  debounce(
    () => (
      // Now if the component is destroyed, it will not unsubscribe from this stream
      isTimerActive.next(true),
      timer(/* ... */)
    )
  ),
  switchMap(v => makeRequest(v)),

  // If the component is destroyed, then after sending this
  // the stream will be unsubscribed
  tap(() => isTimerActive.next(false)),

  takeUntil(stop$)
).subscribe(/* ... */)


ngOnDestroy () {
  this.destroyed.next(true);
  this.destroyed.complete();
}
```

It's important to note that the timer is declared inactive(`isTimerActive.next(false)`) only when we've finished all the tasks that involve the value emitted after the delay.

This is because if `destroyed` is `true` and we immediately do `isTimerActive.next(false)`, the unsubscription will happen **synchronously**, meaning that you won't be able to do anything else with that value.

Comment: Very nice solution. I'm still debating using this or a deactivate guard with a warning to that the user is also warned when leaving the page. But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

To emit the last value that is pending before unsubscribing, you can force the source observable to complete instead of unsubscribing.

```
private unsub$ = new Subject<void>();

this.form.controls.inputControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(unsub$),
    debounceTime(3000)
  ).subscribe(value => {
    // execute HTTP call with value
  });

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.unsub$.next();
}
```

Please note that *takeUntil* must be **before** *debounceTime*, otherwise the last pending value will not be emitted.